# CFD Boundary condition: Pressure far field vs Pressure outlet

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, aerodynamics

I’m confused about a Pressure far field and Pressure outlet boundary condition

Should I be using a pressure far field (for the ‘outlet’ of the computational grid) instead of pressure outlet?

Flow is external, high speed (Mach number= 0.7), over an aerofoil

Comment: What outlet is involved in the flow over an airfoil? Is the airfoil in a wind tunnel?

Comment: Hi sorry I don’t think I understand your question, it’s a CFD simulation so the airfoil is not in a wind tunnel

Comment: My question was about the outlet. There's no outlet involved for an airfoil in free air.